# how to use two different databases in prism JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, prisma

I have a simple prismaJS implementation, but I want to do one thing.

When I'm running in development environment I want to point to a Sqlite database and when running in production I want it to point to a mysql database.

How can I do this in prismaJS keeping the schema and migrations of both databases the same?

Answer (score 2):

Prisma uses a schema.prisma file to define your data model and database configuration. You'll need to set up two configurations, one for SQLite and one for MySQL. Create a file named schema.prisma and define your data model as usual.

```js
// schema.prisma
datasource db {
  provider = "sqlite"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL") // Set this as needed for your environment
}

model User {
  id    Int     
  email String   
  //... and so on
}
```

Create another file named schema.prod.prisma for the production

```js
// schema.prod.prisma
datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL_PROD") // Set this for your production environment
}

// Keep the same model definitions
model User {
  id    Int      
  email String  
  //... and so on
}
```

You need to define the necessary environment variables for both your development and production databases. For SQLite, you can use a local file path, and for MySQL, you'll use a connection URL. In your development environment, you can set the DATABASE_URL environment variable to your SQLite database path. In your production environment, you can set the DATABASE_URL_PROD environment variable to your MySQL connection URL.In your application code, when initializing Prisma, you can conditionally load the appropriate configuration based on the environment.

```js
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client')

let prisma

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  prisma = new PrismaClient({
    datasources: {
      db: {
        url: process.env.DATABASE_URL_PROD, // Use the production database URL
      },
    },
  })
} else {
  prisma = new PrismaClient({
    datasources: {
      db: {
        url: process.env.DATABASE_URL, // Use the development database URL
      },
    },
  })
}

module.exports = prisma
```

Then, depending on the environment (development or production), you can conditionally import the appropriate schema.prisma file. Something like this,

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  require('./schema.prod.prisma')
} else {
  require('./schema.prisma')
}

// Rest of your app setup
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked, I just have a little problem which is the following, when I run a migration in the production database and then try to run it in the dev database it gives an error because the databases are different, I have separate it?

Comment: You are using separate schema files for development and production, the migration files will be generated based on the configuration of the specific schema file you used to generate them. If this schema is consistent across both your development and production configurations, the migration files should work for both databases. But if you're using any features that are specific to one database system and not supported by the other or any prisma virsion compatibility issue , you might encounter issues. But that's a separate issue for which you should raise a new question on stack overflow imo.